# Wait for async thrift requests to complete

Tags: asynchronous, wait, thrift

I am invoking multiple async calls of `thrift` from my code. I would like to wait
for all of them to complete before going on with my next stage.

```
for (...) {
  TNonblockingTransport transport = new TNonblockingSocket(host, port);
  TAsyncClientManager clientManager = new TAsyncClientManager();
  TProtocolFactory protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
  AsyncClient c = new AsyncClient(protocolFactory, clientManager, transport);
  c.function(params, callback);

}

// I would like to wait for all the calls to be complete here.
```

I can have a countdown in the callback like wait/notify and get this done.  But does the `thrift` system allow a way for me to wait on my async function call, preferably with a timeout ?

I didnt see any in the `TAsyncClientManager` or in the `AsyncClient`.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it was not possible to do this, I used the sync api client and managed the launch and wait using executors and launchAll.  I am leaving this as my answer for people to have an alternative.